# How to get hostname on node js/express js without any request

Tags: javascript, node.js

My code is like this

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var rq=require('request');
var url="http://localhost/ss/some.json";
var pages=Object();
rq(url, function (error, response, body) { 
  pages=JSON.parse(body);
});
```

here `var url="http://localhost/ss/some.json";`

i want to get "localhost" without sending any request

i tried

```
require("os").hostname();;
```

but this is returning machine name

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the hostname your service listens to unless you explicitely define it (in configuration) or wait for the request to pull it from there.

The hostname of the machine hosting your service is probably not the hostname your service listens to from the outside.